# Using jQuery to swap div and class position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some call to action buttons on a website that I want to reposition using jQuery. One is a div element & the other a class. They sit vertically. Is it possible to use any function to simply swap their positions or is it a case of altering their CSS? Thanks!

Comment: why *wouldn't* you just use css? you should never use javascript to do something you can do with just css.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the HTML structure and CSS in a way to be able to use Flex Box, after that using some CSS classes and Flex Box, you'll be able to change the layout and the element's position.

You can use jQuery to add or remove one or more classes to the elements responding to the event over the call to actions Using: .addClass() .removeClass() and .toggleClass()

[Flexbox Css Guide.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)